# /api route not reachable after installing Laravel application to Amazon Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services

I've just installed my Laravel application and it loads perfectly. I'm trying to make an api request from my machine to the application and from Vue.js application hosted on S3. Both attempts return 404, and in the browser console it says that I have a CORS problem. Ok, but I've installed fruitcake/cors, and this works locally. Also, I've seen that on AWS, when I try to reach `/api/xxx/xxx`, `index.php` is never reached. If I try without the /api prefix, it's reachable. Could that be a missconfiguration of nginx (I'm using the default configuration, and haven't changed anything)? Any help will be much appreaciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I was thinking, nginx is not configured properly by default. After I've added

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

everything worked.

I am leaving this topic if anyone else has the same problem.

Comment: where should I add this line?